# Application quit dialog prompt with buttons on android using Unity 5.3.4 c#

Tags: c#, android, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity.I need help to set a dialog box prompt with "Yes" & "No" buttons for quitting a game.Dialog box should be generated  when user press "back button".
Currently i am using this code for quitting but it result in accidental exits.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class AndroidExit : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            Application.Quit();
    }
#endif
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: you cannot quit apps on Android or iOS, forget it.  google 100s of pages on it!

Comment: It looks like it's different with Unity, quitting the game doesn't mean kill the app. @Sarun Take a look here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/891781/make-a-button-quit-the-game-unity-64-ui-c.html

Comment: Any idea about using this plugin https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/33552

Comment: @JoeBlow on android you can definitely call Application.Quit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution. I hope it may help others like me :)

Use Mobile Native PopUps plugin (https://unionassets.com/mobile-native-popups)

1.import it to your project

2.you have to move files from (Assets/Plugins/StansAssets to → Assets/Plugins).

3.pass this code to your script(or create a new script)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class AndroidExit : MonoBehaviour
{    
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            MobileNativeDialog dialog = new MobileNativeDialog("Dialog Title", "Dialog message");
            //   Application.Quit();
            dialog.OnComplete += OnDialogClose;
        }
#endif
    }
    private void OnDialogClose(MNDialogResult result)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case MNDialogResult.YES:
                //Debug.Log("Yes button pressed");
                Application.Quit();
                break;
            case MNDialogResult.NO:
                Debug.Log("No button pressed");
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

4.Drag and drop the script to Main Camera in Hierarchy ........